# How to mimic a browser websocket in node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm trying to connect to slack websockets using request url that I have from dev tools. 
Sorry and ty, it's not my kind of thing I guess. Can't find the answer. I want to log messages but without using slack api.

I run v10.16.0 node, it does work for example on this demo of websocket in browser https://www.websocket.org/echo.html, but I wasn't able to get it to work in node.js, I've tried other popular npm packages but wasn't able to get them to work too.

```
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://wss-primary.slack.com/?token=xoxc[SECRET]");
ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Node ws: I keep getting invalid auth as a response.

```
{"type":"error","error":{"code":-1337,"msg":"invalid_auth"}.
```

On browser it sends me normal ws frames, responds to ping pongs, at the beginning correctly receives type:hello message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [websocket library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket), it's as easy as this (which I stole directly from the websocket docs page linked):

```
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;

var client = new WebSocketClient();

client.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
    console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
});

client.on('connect', function(connection) {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    connection.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
    });
    connection.on('close', function() {
        console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
    });
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            console.log("Received: '" + message.utf8Data + "'");
        }
    });

    function sendNumber() {
        if (connection.connected) {
            var number = Math.round(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
            connection.sendUTF(number.toString());
            setTimeout(sendNumber, 1000);
        }
    }
    sendNumber();
});

client.connect('ws://localhost:8080/', 'echo-protocol');
```

Comment: I'm still missing something, I received invalid auth again, I'll try copying all of request headers I have in chrome